# Keep element fixed at top of page on scroll

Tags: html, css

As you can see from the screenshots I have an `<audio>` element which remains at the top of the page on scroll. But I'd like the element to be visable before scrolling begins too.

I can't get this working without messy javascript removing the element and appending it as a child on scroll, any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/772yerga/1/

`html` ..

```
<div class="header">
    <audio controls>
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <span class="banner">LOGO</span>
    <div class="header">Header</div>
</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

`css` ..

```
.header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}
.outer {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}
.outer .banner {
    font-size: 46px;
}
.outer .header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top: auto;
}
.content {
    height: 1500px;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Before scroll ..

[image: before scroll]

After scroll ..

[image: after scroll]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `z-index` of the header to 99 to stay on top - the content scrolls underneath. And added `top: 50px;` to outer - to start a bit lower

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2oyjpkg/

```
   .header {
        background-color: #ccc;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .outer {
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    .outer .banner {
        font-size: 46px;
    }
    .outer .header {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        top: auto;
    }
    .content {
        height: 1500px;
        color: blue;
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
```